# When enabling attachments in SharePoint, List Rest API no longer returns fields related to image columns

Tags: list, rest, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint project that requires that I use a list that contains image columns and enable the attachment column. I found that when I called the API while attachments were enabled, I'd get something like this for my images:

```
<d:Thumbnail>{"fileName":"Reserved_ImageAttachment_[9]_[Thumbnail][10]_[2022-05-09][1]_[3].png"}</d:Thumbnail>
```

Without the "serverRelativeUrl" column, it becomes a difficult task to locate the image because the folder is specific to the item, but is not listed in the field's returned data while attachments are enabled.

If I disable the attachments column I get the results I would expect, something like this when calling the API:

```
<d:Thumbnail>{"fileName":"2022-05-09.png","serverRelativeUrl":"/sites/******/SiteAssets/Lists/d525ac5b-daef-44e7-aec8-d680e300c816/2022-05-09.png","id":"0a1baba3-4abe-4fa5-93f3-9c7180cd9f20","serverUrl":"https://******.sharepoint.com","thumbnailRenderer":null}</d:Thumbnail>
```

Does anyone have any workarounds or ideas to allow me to both use the image column and the attachment column at the same time? Or, am I SOL and need to disable attachments? Then, have my client go through the extra steps of uploading all their files to a folder and finally set up a link column for them to enter each file's url?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running at the exact same problem.

The solution that i found is use the attachments endpoint to retrieve the serverRelativeUrl from the imagem, like this:

/_api/Web/Lists(guid'YOUR LIST GUID HERE')/Items(YOUR ITEM ID HERE)/AttachmentFiles.

Comment: You can do the same in one call for items by doing this: 

/_api/web/lists(guid'YOUR LIST GUID HERE')/items?$expand=AttachmentFiles

The problem is that the images and the attachments are all together in an array with the only identifying factor of the column it belongs to being the newly assigned filename. I suppose I could traverse the attachment file array and compare the filename from the image columns to get the relative URL, but it seems like there has to be a better way (maybe not).